# how to correctly use a scanf and a EOF?

Tags: c, scanf, eof

I am trying to fill my int array with numbers I get from the user.

but when I try to `printf` a specific index that is bigger then, it shows the wrong number.

```
for(B_index=0,checker=0; B_index<SIZE&&!checker; B_index++)
    {

        checker=scanf("%d",&B[B_index]);

        if(checker==EOF)
        {
            checker=1;
        }

        else if(checker<1)
        {
            printf("error");
            return 1;
        }

    }
    printf("%d",B[1]);
```

Comment: This is because C arrays don't do bound checking, i.e., compiler doesn't check if an access to an element in the array is out of the array's bound or not. Why? Two reasons: 1. C arrays convert to pointers in runtime, so every access to an element in array is like doing a pointer arithmetic . 2. Because it gives more speed to the language, it's a trade-off between reliability and speed.

Answer (score 1):

scanf returns the number of assignments back, so if you entered a valid integer on the console, scanf will return 1, which means it assigned an integer (due to %d) to B[0]. This causes checker to be 1 and will hence break the loop immediately after the first number has been entered. B[1] is unassigned and as such will contain garbage or 0 if you cleared out the array.